# Upgrading Http4s to 0.18: StaticFile and fallthrough/pass

Tags: scala, scala-cats, http4s

In Http4s 0.16.6a, I had the following service.

```
import org.http4s.server.staticcontent._
import org.http4s._

object StaticFiles {

  val basepath = ...

  def apply(): HttpService = Service.lift(request => {
    val file = basepath + request.uri.path
    StaticFile.fromString(file, Some(request)).fold {
      Pass.now  // aka fallthrough
    } {
      NoopCacheStrategy.cache(request.pathInfo, _)
    }
  })
}
```

It takes the path from the url and tries to work out if a static file can be served. So a GET request to `/index.html` would try and load it with `fromFile` and if it can't be found, fallthrough or "Pass". When composed with other services using `||`, it meant the total function (from `lift`) would be treated a bit like a partial function (from `apply`).

I can't seem to convert this over to Http4s 0.18.x.

The [Http4s docs](http://http4s.org/v0.18/static/) suggest the following:

```
import cats.effect._
import org.http4s._
import org.http4s.dsl.io._

import java.io.File

val service = HttpService[IO] {
  case request @ GET -> Root / "index.html" =>
    StaticFile.fromFile(new File("relative/path/to/index.html"), Some(request))
      .getOrElseF(NotFound()) // In case the file doesn't exist
}
```

Which is the basic form of what I'm trying to do, only I'd like to generify it a little and not create a partial function for every file I want to serve. i.e. avoid this:

```
case request @ GET -> Root / "index.html" => ???
case request @ GET -> Root / "fileA.html" => ???
case request @ GET -> Root / "fileB.html" => ???
```

So, my questions are:

1. Is there the concept of `Pass` and passthough when using `lift` in 0.18?
2. How to I use the `NooopCacheStretegy` with `lift`?
3. Ultimately, how to I convert the code above to 0.18?

My endeavours so far have lead to this abomination (which obvs doesn't compile):

```
def apply(): HttpService[IO] = HttpService.lift(request => {
  val target = basepath + request.uri.path
  StaticFile.fromString[IO](target, Some(request)).fold {
    // passthrough
    IO.pure(???)
  } {
    // process request
    response => NoopCacheStrategy[IO].cache(request.pathInfo, response).unsafeRunSync()
  }
})
```

Note that I'm trying to use `HttpService.lift` not `OptionT.liftF` (as recommended). Mostly because I have no clue how to!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as far as I can tell, the concept of `Pass` has been replaced by `OptionT` in 0.18.x, with `None` playing the role of `Pass`. However, you don't have access to the `OptionT` with that overload. Instead, the assumption is that since you're passing a partial function to `HttpService`, the requests the function is defined on are precisely the ones you want this service to provide a response for.

You *could* try making it work with `OptionT.lift`, but I wouldn't recommend it either! Instead, I'd make a partial function that's only defined on arguments when your static files exists. The way http4s allows you to define the criteria needed to hit an endpoint through pattern-matching on requests is extremely powerful, and you're completely ignoring that option in both of your solutions.

As far as `NoopCacheStrategy` is concerned, I'm guessing the problem you ran into was that the return type of `StaticFile.fromX` is now `IO[Response[IO]]` and `NoopCacheStrategy` takes a `Response[IO]`. This is easily handled via flatMap.

Which is to say that this is what I came up with to translate your code to 0.18.x:

```
import java.nio.file.{Files, Paths}

import cats.effect.IO
import org.http4s.{HttpService, StaticFile}
import org.http4s.dsl.io._
import org.http4s.server.staticcontent.NoopCacheStrategy

  val service = HttpService[IO] {
    case request @ _ -> _ / file if Files.exists(Paths.get(file)) =>
      StaticFile
        .fromString(file, Some(request))
        .getOrElseF(NotFound())
        .flatMap(resp => NoopCacheStrategy[IO].cache(request.pathInfo, resp))
  }
```

A slight annoyance is that we're actually handling the case where no such file exists twice, once in the if clause of the case statement and once with `getOrElseF`. In practice, that `NotFound` should never be reached. I figure one can live with this.

And as an example of what I mean by the power of http4s' pattern matching on requests, by adjusting the case statement it's very easy to make sure this will only...

- match on GET requests: `case request @ GET -> _ / file if ...`
- match top-level files, nothing in subdirectories: `case request @ _ -> Root / file if ...`
- match HTML files: `case request @ _ -> _ / file ~ html if Files.exists(Paths.get(s"$file.html"))`

You can even write your own custom extractor that checks whether you can serve a given file name to end up with something like `case request @ _ -> _ / ValidStaticFile(file)`. That way you don't have to cram all your logic into the case statement.

Answer (score 0):

I can't seem to format as a comment so posted as a new answer...

How about this?

```
  def apply(): HttpService[IO] = Kleisli.apply(request => {
    val basepath = ...
    val target = location + request.uri.path

    StaticFile.fromString[IO](target, Some(request))
  })
```